# how to be unsafe in yii activerecord saving strings

Tags: security, activerecord, yii, escaping

Yii is saving escaped strings in database when we go through standard model->save() call. I know the security concerns and I still for this case dont want yii to escape my string and save it exactly as in $_POST. how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the saveAttributes() method of ActiveRecord for this.

Use of it:

```
$model = Model::model()->findByPk($id);
$model->saveAttributes(array('field' => 'name', 'field2' => 'name2'));
```

According the class reference:

> Note that this method does neither attribute filtering nor validation.
>   So do not use this method with untrusted data (such as user posted
>   data).

More details:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#saveAttributes-detail

Answer (score 0):

Ah! My environment also had wp-load before yii was loading. And in wp-settings there is a call to `wp_magic_quotes` which I only hunted and found out. so my issue was not actually caused by Yii automatically as I was guessing, it was wordpress which was doing this automatically. For only those of us who use wordpress+yii this problem will be helpfull.